# How can I get text from all html tags using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

my file code will be as under and i want to get all text between `>` and `</` of any tag.

```
<div>
    <h1>This is for testing only.</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>This is Second Paragraph</h2>
</div>
<div>This is directly written on div</div>
<div>
    <p>This is third div paragraph text.</p>
</div>
```

so here i want to get every tag text no matter which tag it is? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code showing us what you have attempted..

Comment: Maybe `$('body').text()` ? :D

Comment: What are you trying to reach because this is kind of confusing ?

Comment: the body text proposed by @BojanPetkovski is probaby the best - see here for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/cd2sgjbh/ you could probably store that as a vairable and then do whatever you wish with the string.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the text in all div elements `$('div').text()`.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.. The OP clearly understands how to get text for a specific html tag, which is why they said "every text no matter which tag it is", implying that they want a universal selector for all tags so they do not have to do $("div"), $("span"), $("p"), etc. etc.

Comment: `$('*').text()` or `$('*').on('click', function(e) { $(e.target).text()})` :D

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally, the solution is `$("*").text()`.

Practically, however, you would scope it to whatever is appropriate. For example:

`$("body *").text()`

`$(".container *").text()`

etc.